# Backup and Restore information from Nokia suite after install / uninstall

Tags: upgrade, nokia-ovi-suite

I use Nokia Ovi Suite in my Windows 7 32-bit PC. I am planning to upgrade to Windows 7 64-bit now. But can I restore and use my existing messages, contacts and other information stored in the Nokia Ovi Suite after this upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way to restore the text messages. In the new versions of `Nokia Suite`, there is an option to import and export text messages. Go to messages, then click `File > Export All Messages`. Save the file to a suitable location. To import the messages, use `File > Import Messages`.